# To have a speed bar in Flash

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cc

I want this

[image]

which I found in a animation about a heart

[image]

One manual [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/flash_reference.pdf) but too little details and very basics. 
ActionScript 3 most probably the latest programming language in Flash, but I cannot find [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3), for instance the function `changeFps`.

**How can you have such a speed bar for an animation?** 
Any package for this?

Comment: It's just a slider which control the "function" that do the animation. So this "function" is more important than the slider. Could you show us what have you tried ?

Comment: @akmozo I have just done a simple animation with a movement in Adobe Flash CC 2014, but cannot find anywhere there a slider.

Comment: The general problem was to link some symbolic computation to visualisation. I get a feedback from my friends that such a problem is much easier to be completed in Mathematica only: visualising expansion of atrias and ventricles; electric conduction system; pacemakers and ECG changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `component` Slider named *slider* on your stage:

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

var val:Number = 30;

slider.value = val;
slider.maximum = 100;
slider.minimum = 20;

myFps.text = val + " fps";
stage.frameRate = val;

slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, changeFps);

function changeFps(e:SliderEvent):void {
    val = e.target.value;
    stage.frameRate = val;
    myFps.text = val + " fps";
}
```

Comment: Any link to the manual about this? One manual here http://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/flash_reference.pdf but too little details and very basics.

Comment: ActionScript 3? I cannot find here, for instance the function `changeFps`, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/

Comment: @Masi changeFps isn't a native function, but simply used to modify the stage.frameRate.

Comment: Should it be here documented? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/SliderEvent.html